# what are loaded(modifiers ,blocks ,methods) along or prior to the class loading in java?

Tags: java

i am  having question which of the follwing methods ,variables, blocks are loaded at the time of class loading in java irrespective of object creation and not accessing them through object??

```
1. static variables 
2. static methods 
3. final variables,methods 
4. static blocks 
5. instance ({..... })blocks
6. main()
7. constructors (argumented and default)
8. instance variables
```

which of them is loaded at the time class loading in java?? 
*(order of loading is not required i just wanna know what are loaded prior or along with class loading in java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class is initialised, all the meta data is loaded for that class.  However, little is done until it is used.  For each of the stages you mention, they are performed when they are first run.

Comment: i mean if there is a static method like public static void main() and normal other static method which will be loaded first main method or  other static method??

Comment: The methods you use are loaded in the order you use them.  The static fields will be initialised first (in the order they appear)

Comment: Every part of a class is *loaded* at the same time; for the JVM, it's all just a byte array. There is no order for loading methods. Class loading should not be confused with *static class initialization*, though, which happens later and where the static fields are initialized in the textual order as they appear in source code.

Answer (score 1):

When the JVM loads a class, it load the `.class` file with everything it contains, which is all of what you listed above. Of course this doesn't mean all that is actually *executed*.

**EDIT**: It looks like you think that each part of the class (fields, methods, etc...) is a different part and is loaded separately. This is not the case. The .class file contains all of a class parts and they're loaded at the same time, when the .class is loaded into memory. Maybe your confusion comes on how reflection is used, where you have `Class`, `Method`, `Contructor` and such classes. These are actually *virtual* parts created by the JVM when it parses the .class file to allow features like reflection.

Comment: no actually which are loaded  along with class and  can be accessed directly without object creation ???

Comment: @user2199330 You can access static fields and methods without an instance, but you should know that already.  Perhaps you could make your point clearer?

Comment: i mean if there is a static method like public static void main() and normal other static method which will be loaded first main method or  other static method??

Comment: The .class contains all the code for that class, and as such both static and instance methods are loaded at the same time. For the JVM the .class is just a file to load into memory.